# MySQL connection access on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos

Some program is trying to constantly access my MySql database.

I can see in the general log:

```
130424  0:43:59   112 Connect   Access denied for user 'lucas'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
          112 Connect   lucas@localhost as  on 
130424  0:44:01   113 Connect   Access denied for user 'lucas'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
          113 Connect   lucas@localhost as  on 
130424  0:44:03   114 Connect   Access denied for user 'lucas'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I cannot find the source of the requests.

I am running Mac OS 10.8.

Comment: try `lsof -i` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof

Comment: Hello, couldn't identify the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still experiencing this issue, it is a bug with MySQL widget in the System Preferences. See more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012711/register-the-pid-that-tries-to-connect-in-the-mysql-log